# gtk_adjustment_value_changed method

Tags: gtk

what does **gtk_adjustment_value_changed** method signify. 
Can i increment gtk_adjustment_value_changed value instead of **value**

Regards,
iSight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [`gtk_adjustment_value_changed()`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkAdjustment.html#gtk-adjustment-value-changed), you will see that there is no value for you to increment. This method tells the `GtkAdjustment` object to emit a notification to any object that is listening to the `value-changed` signal. You shouldn't have to use it in a normal application.

Comment: Yes, got it. Whenever the value of adjustment object changed i have to call the gtk_adjustment_value_changed method() whereby the listening object(scrolledwindow object in my case) will act accordingly. sample as under:hadj->set_value(value);
   hadj->value_changed();